# reload urdf for robot_state_publisher?

Tags: robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently improving the calibration procedure for my robot and create an urdf-file according to some
calibration values. After I have measured a new value (e.g. maximal position for an axis), I update the urdf file and upload it to the parameter server. However, the robot_state_publisher does not reload this parameter regularly so that a change of the robot-description-Parameter is not reflected e.g. in RVIZ.

I currently just kill the robot_state_publisher (and launch it with respawn), but that it's a bit ugly. I don't care if the frames are jumping after the reload, I'd just be happy to have a possibility to specify and update-intervall so that the param is read regularly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212822/reload-urdf-for-robot_state_publisher?/) by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3519 on 2015-07-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not possible another way at the moment.
However, I'd like to see a way to reload this as well (e.g. by calling a service or something).

You could either send a [feature request](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/issues) or implement it yourself and send a [PR](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/pulls) (which might be preferable as currently I don't know who is actually working on this).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2015-07-03**:
Thanks. I'll open a feature request and if others also need it, I\m going to implement it. [Issue can be found here](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/issues/29)